# get a number or string from void method MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my Controller i have a method like this:

```
public string _Count(int id)
{
    return (repositoryModeli_marka.Modeli_marka.Count(c => c.parent == id).ToString());
}
```

and then in my view i call this method with:

```
@foreach (var i in Model)
{    
Html.RenderAction("_Count", "Modeli_marka", new { id = i.id })
}
```

and this works fine. I get the count number i my view.
Now i need to check this number, something like this:

```
@foreach (var i in Model)
{    
if (Html.RenderAction("_Count", "Modeli_marka", new { id = i.id }) == "")
    {
    }
}
```

and i cant do that becouse it say void == int or == string. How can i accomplish this?

thx in advance

Comment: This doesn't make sense architecturally wise.

Comment: i know...but you can see what i want to do. do you have suggestion how to do this?

Comment: Sure, my suggestion is don't. You have some kind of logic in your other view that shouldn't be there. I'd suggest instead moving that logic into a model/controller/helper, anything but the view.

Comment: what is it you wanna do? it is not clear.

Comment: i have bad database where i need to count models (i did that) and if that count if 0 you can delete that model if is null you cant. i dont want to recreate database and all info in it. so im trying to do it this way.

Comment: So you want to hide the view if it is blank or you just want to get a count of views that are not blank, I'm still confused.

Comment: Why don't you do the model iteration in the controller, then just pass the results to the view?  You reduce db calls this way.